# Angular 2: What does variable name with ? mean?

Tags: angular, typescript

What does variable name with ? mark mean ? e.g.

```
Label?: string
```

I see this in lots of places and couldn't understand what it means.

Comment: ? means optional in  Angular2/TypeScript

Comment: @Rich Please stop calling it Angular2. It's not Angular2, it's just Angular. I really hope you've moved past the version 2.x.x.

Answer (score 4):

`?` indicates the parameter is optional. This is something specific to `typescript` - not `angular` or `javascript` (in javascript, all parameters are optional by default).

From `Typescript` [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html),

> In JavaScript, every parameter is optional, and users may leave them off as they see fit. When they do, their value is undefined. We can get this functionality in TypeScript by adding a ? to the end of parameters we want to be optional.

```
 function buildName(firstName: string, lastName?: string) {
     if (lastName)
         return firstName + " " + lastName;
     else
         return firstName; }

let result1 = buildName("Bob");                  // works correctly now 
let result2 = buildName("Bob", "Adams", "Sr.");  // error, too many parameters 
let result3 = buildName("Bob", "Adams"); // ah, just right
```